# Angular material mat-error cannot show message

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have 2 datetime picker, endDate cannot be less than startDate

```
endDateAfterOrEqualValidator(formGroup): any {
    var startDateTimestamp: number;
    var endDateTimestamp: number;
    startDateTimestamp = Date.parse(formGroup.controls['startDateForm'].value);
    endDateTimestamp = Date.parse(formGroup.controls['endDateForm'].value);
    return (endDateTimestamp < startDateTimestamp) ? { endDateLessThanStartDate: true } : null;
  }
```

in html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput  name="endDate" id="endDate" formControlName="endDateForm" [(ngModel)]="endDate" [matDatepicker]="toDatePicker"
    placeholder="To Date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker disabled="false" #toDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="trainingDetail.hasError('endDateLessThanStartDate')">Not valid<mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

with "mat-error", the message does not display. I try to change by "small"

```
<small *ngIf="trainingDetail.hasError('endDateLessThanStartDate')">Not valid</small>
```

the message well. Please advice me how to using mat-error

Answer (score 35, accepted):

a `mat-error` only shows when a **FormControl** is invalid, but you have the validation on your formgroup. So in that case you need to use a [`ErrorStateMatcher`](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown)

In your case it would look like this:

```ts
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const invalidCtrl = !!(control && control.invalid);
    const invalidParent = !!(control && control.parent && control.parent.invalid);

    return (invalidCtrl || invalidParent);
  }
}
```

Also worth mentioning, it's not recommended to have two bindings, i.e `formControl` and `ngModel`. Remove the `ngModel` and utilize the form control instead. If you receive your start date and end date at a later point, you can use `patchValue` (just set some values to form) or `setValue` (set all values to form)

mark in component the errorstatematcher:

```ts
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

As for your custom validator, you don't need to parse the dates, just check if end date is smaller than start date:

```ts
checkDates(group: FormGroup) {
  if (group.controls.endDate.value < group.controls.startDate.value) {
    return { endDateLessThanStartDate: true }
  }
  return null;
}
```

and then mark the error state matcher in your template:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" type="text" formControlName="endDate" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.hasError('endDateLessThanStartDate')">End date cannot be earlier than start date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here's a **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhbuqn?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html)**

Comment: Thank you so much, it's good demo. But I change the End Date to the invalid date. this error message not display

Comment: What do you mean that you changed the end date to the invalid date? Could you demonstrate in the demo I made?

Comment: Your default startDate in ts is 2017-11-25T22:00:00.000Z. But on UI display 11/26/2017 (maybe time zone). I try to change startDate first to 11/25/2017, and change invalid endDate. The error is displayed. Thanks

Comment: @AJT_82 Is it possible to add "required" error state along with this custom validation? Thanks in adv.

Comment: I have a question here please, what's the use of `form: FormGroupDirective` in the `isErrorState` method. It's not used, so we can remove it right?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a control as invalid from the .ts file manually...

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input matInput [formControl]="exampleFormControl" (change)="changeDetected()">
  <mat-hint>(Optional)</mat-hint>
  <mat-error *ngIf="exampleFormControl.hasError('invalid')">
      Must be a <strong>valid input</strong>!
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'derp',
  templateUrl: './derp.html',
  styleUrls: ['./derp.scss'],
})
export class ExampleClass {

  // Date Error Form Control
  exampleFormControl = new FormControl('');

  // Variable Check
  inputValid: boolean;

  changeDetected() {
    // Check if input valid
    if (this.inputValid) {
      console.log('Valid Input');
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid Input');
      // IMPORTANT BIT - This makes the input invalid and resets after a form change is made
      this.exampleFormControl.setErrors({
        invalid: true,
      });
    }
  }

  // CODE THAT CHANGES VALUE OF 'inputValid' //

}
```