# How to display different error messages based on user input in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am new to angular 6 ,Here I want to validate a user input field and display different error messages based on the given input.

In my project I am using Angular Material design for UI.

What I want to do is

- If the user click on the save button display a error message as **"Please enter your FName".**
- If user touched but not enter anything and clicked on save button display a error message as **"Please enter your FName".**
- If user  started to enter char it should show a error message as **"minimum 4 char required"**
- Once the user reached 15 char it should show a error message as **"Maximum 20 char only"**
- If the user enter any special char and space and other input an error message as **"Enter only alphabets"**

Now it changes to RED  color when the input does not meet the successful validation.but I want to display an error message for each validation in the formControl.

Here I have a mat-input-field.

```
<form [formGroup]="userAddressValidations" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-sm-6">
        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>

<button mat-raised-button class="continueBtnHeight" color="warn">
<span>Save</span>
</button>
```

Ts file

```
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  userAddressValidations: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userAddressValidations = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]+')]]
    });

  }
}
```

stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1k1x6-skowwq?file=app%2Fbutton-toggle-overview-example.ts

can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Use `mat-error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userAddressValidations">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName">
    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
      First Name is Required!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('minlength')">
      First Name should be atleast 4 characters long!
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('maxlength')">
      First Name can be atmax n characters long!
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('pattern')">
      First Name must follow this pattern!
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: It's showing only the FirstName is required validation. other messages are not working. @SiddAjmera

Comment: Updated the answer. There was an issue with the case of error names. `minLength` should have been `minlength`

Comment: Here If the user starts with special character error message should be as the "First Name must follow this pattern!" instead of minimum char error. If I am right how to do it brother @SiddAjmera

Comment: You might want to change the sequence of error messages. I think there's a priority sequence. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Sidd, is right. @Zhu. Just change the order your ts. file

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417652/how-to-validate-input-fields-one-by-one-in-angular-6?noredirect=1#comment91778499_52417652 @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 1):

use `hasError('invalidName')`  for if the user enter any special char and space

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cannot-read-property-of-custom-validator-and-required-an-ujgzqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

> Component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="userAddressValidations">

    <label>User Name : 
        <input type="text"  formControlName="firstName">
    </label><br>

    <div class="errors" *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').invalid && (userAddressValidations.get('firstName').touched || userAddressValidations.get('firstName').dirty)">

        <div *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
            Please enter your FName
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').errors.minlength">
            minimum 4 char required
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').errors.maxlength">
            Maximum 20 char only
        </div>

        <div class="error-text" *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('invalidName')">
            Enter only alphabets
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

> Component.ts

```
this.userAddressValidations = fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20), usernameValidator]]
});
```

> username.validators.ts

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms"

export const usernameValidator = function (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

  let value: string = control.value || '';

  if (value) {
    const matches = value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
    return matches ? null : { 'invalidName': true };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here If the user starts with special character error message should be as the "First Name must follow this pattern!" instead of minimum char error. If I am right how to do it brother @Krishna Rathore

Comment: add this condition

<div *ngIf="!userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('invalidName') && userAddressValidations.get('firstName').errors.minlength">
   minimum 4 char required
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this tutorial https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/model-driven-validation, You can also reference to this stackoverflow question: [Display custom validator error with mat-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884655/display-custom-validator-error-with-mat-error)

But here's a small example:

```
<form [formGroup]="userAddressValidations" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-sm-6">
        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
         <mat-error *ngIf="email.errors.required">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
         <mat-error *ngIf="email.errors.minlength">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```