# Angular 2+, why doesn't material want to show error message?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I want to confirm the passwords, but when I wrote the logic of validator and send it to the `mat-error` the message haven't shown, but the validator work normally, how fix this moment in reactive forms in my case??

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  profileForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
     private userService: UserService,
     private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+$/)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(.{8,100})$/)]],
      passwordConfirm: ['', [Validators.required]]
    },
      { validator: this.checkPasswords }
    );
  }

  checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
    let pass = group.get('password').value;
    let confirmPass = group.get('passwordConfirm').value;

    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { mismatch: true }     
  }   

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get name(){
    return this.profileForm.get('name');
  }

  get email(){
    return this.profileForm.get('email');
  }

  get password(){
    return this.profileForm.get('password')
  }

  get passwordConfirm(){
    return this.profileForm.get('passwordConfirm')
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.warn(this.profileForm.value);
    this.userService.createUser(this.profileForm.value);    
  }

}
```

in html code

```
<form class="form-to-submit" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <div class="form-input-position">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  >
                <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" required> 
                <mat-icon matSuffix>supervised_user_circle</mat-icon>

                <mat-error *ngIf="name.hasError('required')">
                    Field should be <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="name.hasError('pattern')">
                    Field should use <strong>Latin alphabet</strong> 
                </mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-position">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  >
                <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" required>
                <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon> 

                <mat-error *ngIf="email.hasError('required')">
                    Field should be <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="email.hasError('pattern')">
                    Use right <strong>email format</strong> 
                </mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-position">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  >
                <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required> 
                <mat-icon matSuffix>lock</mat-icon>

                <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
                    Field should be <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('pattern')">
                    Should be <strong>minimum 8 elements, one uppercase letter, one number</strong> 
                </mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-position">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  >
                <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" formControlName="passwordConfirm" required> 
                <mat-icon matSuffix>lock</mat-icon>

                <mat-error *ngIf="passwordConfirm.hasError('required')">
                    Field should be <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>

                {{profileForm.hasError('mismatch')}}
                <mat-error *ngIf="profileForm.hasError('mismatch')">
                    Password <strong>mistmached</strong>
                </mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="form-input-button">
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Cancel</button>
        </div>


    </form>
```

this case I have tried ([Confirm password validation in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6) solution) but the problem in error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SignUpComponent' declared by the
>   module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component
>   annotation.

and if I am right it is `template-driven forms` not a reactive way

**Node**

my `app.modul.ts` file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { MatIconModule,
     MatMenuModule,
     MatInputModule,
     MatButtonModule
     } from '@angular/material';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
AppComponent,
SignUpComponent,
LoginComponent,
HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatMenuModule,
MatIconModule,
MatInputModule,
MatButtonModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,    
HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Node 2**

I have read the https://itnext.io/materror-cross-field-validators-in-angular-material-7-97053b2ed0cf

and this https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

this links told about the ErrorStateMatcher implementation to touch the input. Well I changed my code

in sign-up.component.ts

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
   isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
  return control.dirty && form.invalid;
  }
}
```

> If we started typing something in the input, and the form itself is invalid, state that the control has errors.

create the object `errorMatcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();` in sign in `class SignUpComponent`

my form in ts file looks like

```
this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+$/)]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(.{8,100})$/)]],
  passwordConfirm: ['']
},
  { validator: this.passwordValidator }
);
}

passwordValidator(form: FormGroup) {
  const condition = form.get('password').value !== form.get('verifyPassword').value;

  return condition ? { passwordsDoNotMatch: true} : null;
}
```

and finally  html file

```
<input matInput type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" formControlName="passwordConfirm" required
                       [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"> 
                <mat-icon matSuffix>lock</mat-icon>

                <mat-error *ngIf="passwordConfirm.hasError('required')">
                    Field should be <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>

                {{profileForm.hasError('mismatch')}}
                <mat-error 
*ngIf="profileForm.hasError('passwordsDoNotMatch')">
                    Field should be <strong>AAAAA</strong>
                </mat-error>
                <p 
*ngIf="profileForm.hasError('passwordsDoNotMatch')">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

However, I have a big problem which stop downloading form

> compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SignUpComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

I've tried to fix it (add to @NgModule next lines)

```
 providers: [
{ provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: ShowOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher }
 ],
```

but it didn't help me

Comment: can you share stackblitz demo?

Comment: There are many reasons of this error message. Check your imports in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Share: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhbuqn-s5lmtv?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts

Comment: jess - if you mean to check the BrowserModule, FormsModule I checked. Wait a minute i'll add my app module

Comment: the error is an error of formGroup, not of the formControl, create a customError over the control, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update**

To create a customFormControl over a control, we use parent, see  an example

```
checkPasswords(): ValidatorFn {
    //see that the argument is a FormControl
    return (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => {
      //the formGroup is control.parent
      const group = control.parent as FormGroup;
      //but we must sure that is defined
      if (!group) return null;
      console.log(group.get("password").value);
      let pass = group.get("password").value;
      let confirmPass = group.get("passwordConfirm").value;

      return confirmPass ? pass === confirmPass ? null : { mismatch: true } : null;
    };
  }
```

As we want to make check when password change too

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get("password").valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.form.get("passwordConfirm").updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
```

See that the form is like

```
form = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    passwordConfirm: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,
      this.checkPasswords()
    ])
  });
```

And the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="password" formControlName="password">
        <mat-error >
      required
    </mat-error>

  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="repeat password" formControlName="passwordConfirm"
           >
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('mismatch')">
      must matcher
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('required')">
      required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y88jq4?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html)

The other way is using a custom errorStateMatcher

**Update 2** I said that other way is "use a errorStateMatcher." A erroStateMatcher is a simple function that return true or false. If return true, our control will be marked as if he was invalid(*)

Imagine we has a form like

```
form = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    passwordConfirm: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,

    ])
  },this.checkPasswords());
```

See that error is belong to formGroup, we can create a customErrorMatcher that return true if control is invalid or if form.hasError('mismatch`)

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!((control && form.hasError('mismatch') || control.invalid) && control.touched );
  }
}
```

Well, the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="password" formControlName="password">
        <mat-error >
      required
    </mat-error>

  </mat-form-field>
<!--see that the "errorStateMatcher" is applied to the input "passwordConfirm"-->
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="repeat password" formControlName="passwordConfirm"
    [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
           >
      <!--here show the error is form.hasError('mismatch')-->
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('mismatch')">
      must matcher
    </mat-error>
       <!--here show the error is form.get('passwordConfirm').hasError-->
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('required')">
      required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

As always I can, [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfgwtc?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html)

(*) check in the stackblitz form.get('passwordConfirm').invalid

Comment: after this line `const group=control.parent;` the method(debugging) ends, and the validator isn't work

Comment: check the name of your FormControls, see an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y88jq4?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html

Comment: It's work but it's not good solution, because I have required validation, and in the required field, it shows both error messages, I try 1 more solution to fix. If it's possible can you read node 2

Comment: Huge thank you, I take just error in the second case, you answer help me. Thank you for your time and helping)

Comment: @remk93, I updated the answer adding if you want use a customErrorStateMatch