# <mat-error> not showing inside <mat-form-field> of a reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form in my angular app for login. I am trying to display form validation erros, but they won't show unless I place them outside `<mat-form-field>`.

I've tried adding an `ErrorStateMatcher` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544505/angular-material-mat-error-cannot-show-message), but it won't work. I have copy pasted the same form structure that works for me in other components of the application. Here it is:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" #formDir="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" autocomplete="off" matInput placeholder="Email"
            formControlName="username" name="username">
        <mat-icon matSuffix>alternate_email</mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['username'].hasError('required')">
            * This field is required
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" autocomplete="off" matInput placeholder="Password"
            formControlName="password" type="password" name="password" autocomplete>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>vpn_key</mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')">
            * this field is required
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here it is my form instance:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])

    })
  }
```

Although the error messages are not displaying, **the fields turn red** when they are not valid (both Validators.required and Validators.email seem to be working).

I've also tried forcing the inputs to have errors on submit, only for testing purposes as I don't think it is a proper solution, like this:

```
    this.loginForm.controls['username'].setErrors({
      required: true
    })
    this.loginForm.controls['password'].setErrors({
      required: true
    })
    this.loginForm.markAllAsTouched();
    this.loginForm.controls['username'].markAsTouched();
    this.loginForm.controls['password'].markAsTouched();
```

These are the modules that I imported on app.module:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299931/angular-2-why-doesnt-material-want-to-show-error-message/58300325#58300325

Comment: @Eliseo I am not using a custom validator, just Validators.required and Validators.email

Comment: sorry, I confused your question with another. try using "get":  `*ngIf="loginForm.get('password')?.hasError('required')"`: NOTE if only has an error, you can remove the *ngIf

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for the suggestion, but it is not working either. I use *ngIf for testing purposes, initially I was not using it.

Comment: remove `#formDir="ngForm"` and `[errorStateMatcher]="matcher"`. By defect, the errors are showed when has error and are touched. At first you can maskAllasTouched if you want show it always

Comment: @Eliseo I use ngForm to subscribe submission and show/hide messages based on that. Also, I already tried markAllAsTouched as you can see in my above example .