# How to pass Form Group control value to a Custom Validator which uses in the same Form Group?

Tags: angular

I have a custom validator to check retype confirm

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function RetypeConfirm(confirmpassword: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (control.value !== confirmpassword) {
             return { 'mismatch': true };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

My typescript file

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { RetypeConfirm } from 'app/validators/retype-confirm.validator';

passwordChangeForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
     this.passwordChangeForm = this.fb.group({
         newPassword: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegEx.STRONG_PASSWORD)]],
         confirmpassword: ["", [Validators.required, RetypeConfirm(***I want to pass passwordChangeForm.controls['newPassword'].value  here****  )]]
     });
}
```

I need to pass `this.passwordChangeForm.controls['newPassword'].value` to RetypeConfirm custom validator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6

Comment: @鸿则_ thnks. In there `checkPasswords(group: FormGroup)` is in the same typescript file. Only can check controllers with name password, and confirmPass. But i need to use confirm any two values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function get the password field and compare with confirm password

```
function RetypeConfirm(newpassword: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl) => {

        if (!control || !control.parent) {
            return null;
        }
        return control.parent.get(newpassword).value === control.value ? null : { mismatch: true };
    };
}
```

And you can directly pass the value of password from group

```
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
    newpassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
    confirmPassword: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        RetypeConfirm('newpassword')
  ]]
});
```

And the html,

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
    <label>New Password</label>
    <input  formControlName="newpassword" />
    <br>
    <label> Confirm Password</label>
    <input name="confirmPassword"  formControlName="confirmPassword"/>

    <span *ngIf=" signUpForm.get('confirmPassword').errors?.mismatch">Password Confirmation must match password</span>

</form>
```

**Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cross-password-validation-with-parameter)**.

Answer (score 2):

You don't forcibly need to pass it that way as the SDK does allow you to have what you want using the parent field of the **[AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)** giving you the **FormGroup reference**, here is how:

```
export const RetypeConfirmValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

    if (!control.parent || !control) {
        return null;
    }

    const newPassword = control.parent.get('newPassword');          // The new password
    const confirmpassword = control.parent.get('confirmpassword');  // The retyped password

    if (!newPassword || !confirmpassword){
        return null;
    }

    if (confirmpassword.value === ''){
        return null;
    }

    if (newPassword.value === confirmpassword.value){
        return null;
    }

    return { 'mismatch': true };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function RetypeConfirm(confirmpassword: string) {
    return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (!control || !control.parent) {
            return null;
        }
        if (control.value !== control.parent.get(confirmpassword).value) {
            return { 'mismatch': true };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

In your typescript file

```
this.passwordChangeForm = this.fb.group({
      newPassword: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegEx.STRONG_PASSWORD)]],
      confirmpassword: ["", [Validators.required, RetypeConfirm('newPassword')]],
    });
```

How to pass that value : `RetypeConfirm('newPassword')`