# Angular reactive form validate input based on two other input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have three input fields, namely

1. Minimum score
2. Maximum score
3. Origin at

So, `origin at` value must be between minimum score and maximum score.

My form looks like this

```
this.fb.group({
    min: ['', [Validators.required]],
    max: ['', [Validators.required]],
    origin: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(?), Validators.max(?)]] # I need value of min and max input field value here
})
```

[image]

How do I validate origin input field properly?

**EDIT:**

NOTE - `fb` is `FormBuilder`

My entire form

```
this.scalesForm = this.fb.group({
  scales: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      type: ['x', [Validators.required]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      components: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),
      min: ['', [Validators.required]],
      max: ['', [Validators.required]],
      origin: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }),
    this.fb.group({
      type: ['y', [Validators.required]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      components: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),
      min: ['', [Validators.required]],
      max: ['', [Validators.required]],
      origin: ['', [Validators.required]]
    })
  ])
});
```

Comment: You seem to need something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606362/11498076

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use a custom validator, in your case something like:

```
export function ValidateOrigin(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
  if (control.value < this.scalesForm.controls.scales[0].controls.min.value && control.value > this.scalesForm.controls.scales[0].controls.max.value) {
    return { invalidOrigin: true };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// in the form declaration
this.fb.group({
  min: ['', [Validators.required]],
  max: ['', [Validators.required]],
  origin: ['', [Validators.required, ValidateOrigin]]
})
```

Comment: Shoudl it be `if (control.value < this.fb.controls.min.value || control.value > this.fb.controls.max.value) {`  as that is the condition when error shoudl be reported.  Alternatively, you need to use `return null` in `if` block.  Currently, it seems implemented other way round.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @axl-code! Please see updated post. But my form is a form array with two form groups. How can I know from which to select the min and max? (from type: x or type: y)

Comment: I've updated my answer, check if it works with that structure. But basically I'll create 2 different validation functions (or a parametric generic one for both), one for the x and another one for the y, changing the index of the scales property

Comment: you need make the custom form Control over the **full group**, what happens if you change the min after change origin?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom validator. First you would need to create your form controls as local variables to make their instances available for your dependent control like this:

```
const minFormControl = this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]);
const maxFormControl = this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]);
```

Then you can create your group and add all controls there using a custom validator like this:

```
this.fb.group({
    min: minFormControl,
    max: maxFormControl,
    origin: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.validateMin(minFormControl), CustomValidators.validateMax(maxFormControl)])
})
```

Then in those you can implement your validation logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Blind Despair. I'll need to create lots of variables/controls just for this because I have this group inside an form array as in the updated post.