# Validate one input field of angular reactive form depending on the value of another

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a angular reactive form with input fields
HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="ExampleForm">
<input formControlName="Key" id="Key" type="text" 
     [attr.aria-required]="ExampleForm.get('Key').errors ? ExampleForm.get('Key').errors.required ? 'true' : null : null"
     [attr.data-invalid]="(isControlInvalid('Key')) ? 'true' : null"/>
     <div>"error1"</div>


<input formControlName="Value" id="Value" type="text" 
     [attr.aria-required]="ExampleForm.get('Value').errors ? ExampleForm.get('Value').errors.required ? 'true' : null : null"
     [attr.data-invalid]="(isControlInvalid('Value') || validateValue()) ? 'true' : null"/>
     <div *ngIf = "validateValue()">"error1"</div>
     <div *ngIf = "ExampleForm.get('Value').errors ? ExampleForm.get('Value').errors.required ? 'true' : null : null">"error2"</div>
```

I have ts file as

```
this.ExampleForm = this.fb.group({
            Key: ["", Validators.required],
            Value: ["", Validators.required]
        });

validateValue() {
        let key = this.ExampleForm.get("Key").value;
        let value = this.ExampleForm.get("Value").value;
        if ((value && value.length > 0) && (key === "Apple")) {
            this.ExampleForm.get("Value").setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9A-Za-z .-]+$")]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I need to validate "value" field based on the text present in "key" and show error messages accordingly.
with the above code both error messages pop up if the text is according to validation also..How can i achieve this?

Comment: It is basically the same scenario as with "password" and "repeat password" scenario. Take a look, for example. at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6

Comment: @MaciejKasprzak Thank you,How about doing in this method...from HTML? and im applying this logic while editing the field too