# reactive forms equal password validations

Tags: angular, typescript

the sign-up button only enables if signupForm is valid , but right now I have one issue , the button is enabling even though the password and confirm password does not match

is my  this.equalWithPasswordValidator. implementation wrong ?

Any idea ? Thanks.

#html code

```
 <button mat-raised-button class="full-width v-btn-lrg mt-0px" color="primary" type="submit"
            [disabled]="signupForm.invalid">
            {{labels.BUTTON.SETUP}}
          </button>
```

#ts code

```
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      confirmPassword: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, this.equalWithPasswordValidator.bind(this)],
        
      ],
      password: [
        '',
        [
          this.validatePasswordRequired,
          this.validateMinimumPassword,
          this.validatePasswordUpperCase,
          this.validatePasswordLowerCase,
          this.validatePasswordSpecialCharacter,
          this.validateOneNumber,
        ],
      ],
    });
  }

  equalWithPasswordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const equal = control.value === this.signupForm.get('password').value;
      return equal ? { notEqual: { value: 'Passwords do not match' } } : null;
    };
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confirm password validation in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6)

Comment: No Sir , it does not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a validator to the FormGroup so you can get access to both controls. Here's one approach to creating a validator to compare two fields...

```js
  // component

  form = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl('', [ yourValidators... ]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [ yourValidators... ])
  }, {
    validators: [ equivalentValidator('password', 'confirmPassword') ]
  });


  // equivalent.validator.ts

  import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
    
  export const equivalentValidator = (firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string): ValidatorFn => {
    
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const firstControl = control.get(firstControlName);
      const secondControl = control.get(secondControlName);
    
      if (secondControl.value && secondControl.value !== firstControl.value) {
        secondControl.setErrors({ notEqual: true });
      }
    
      return null;
    };
    
  };
```

In this example, I'm only setting an error on the second field if it doesn't match the first. Instead of setting the error message here, I'm just setting an error of `notEqual` so the validator can be re-used across forms.