# Angular validation

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a form validation. I have three fields: `firstname`, `password`, `confirm_password`. Next to the `name` field I try to display an error in `span` that I need to fill in the name field, but it is shown to me immediately. Also, I'm trying to validate password storage, but it doesn't work for me
I have 2 questions: How can I make the error appear only when sending the form and not when typing the text and what do I do wrong when validating on matching passwords? Thanks

`registration.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-registration',
   templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})

confirm_password_validator(control: AbstractControl) {
   if (this.confirm_password.value != this.password.value) {
     return {word: 'Паролі не збігаються'}
   }
  return null;
}

firstname = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
confirm_password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), this.confirm_password_validator])

registrationForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstname: this.firstname,
   password: this.password,
   confirm_password: this.confirm_password
});

   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

`registration.component.html`

```
<form class="registration_form" [formGroup]="registrationForm">

<div class="different_input">
<span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['firstname'].errors?.['required']">Field can't be empty</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type username..." [formControl]="firstname">
</div>

<div class="different_input">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Create password..." [formControl]="password">
</div>

<div class="different_input">
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password..." [formControl]="confirm_password">
</div>
<button>Create</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your code and add touched validation to input like this for error shown immediately

```
<form class="registration_form" [formGroup]="registrationForm">

<div class="different_input">
<span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['firstname'].errors?.['required'] 
 && registrationForm.controls['firstname']?.touched">Field can't be empty</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type username..." [formControl]="firstname">
</div>

<div class="different_input">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Create password..." [formControl]="password">
</div>

<div class="different_input">
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password..." [formControl]="confirm_password">
</div>
<button>Create</button>

</form>
```

for appear error only when sending the form you can add some configuration to the formGroup like this

```
firstname = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
confirm_password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), this.confirm_password_validator])

registrationForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstname: this.firstname,
   password: this.password,
   confirm_password: this.confirm_password
} , { updateOn:'submit' });
```

and for validation your password matching rewrite your function to something like this i think it will work but I'm not entirely sure :( for more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6/55929868) it will help you

```
confirm_password_validator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl):  ValidationErrors | null => { 
  let pass = control.get('password').value;
  let confirmPass = control.get('confirm_password').value
  return pass === confirmPass ? null : { word: 'Паролі не збігаються' }
}
```