# My Reactive Form it's returning undefined before I do the Validations in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, undefined, angular-reactive-forms

The console error: I'm getting this error because the form seems to be requesting the data before I can get a value and it's rendering the component itself, I'm new to this technology, let me know if this is the way to do it or where should I look for the info any help would be great!

```html
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at FormGroup.checkPassword (register.component.ts:30:59)
    at FormGroup._runValidator (forms.mjs:2261:38)
    at FormGroup.updateValueAndValidity (forms.mjs:2238:32)
    at new FormGroup (forms.mjs:2641:14)
    at FormBuilder.group (forms.mjs:7136:16)
    at new RegisterComponent (register.component.ts:14:29)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.RegisterComponent_Factory [as factory] (register.component.ts:32:4)
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  register: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.register = this.fb.group({
      usuario: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      repeatPassword: ['']
    }, { validator: this.checkPassword});
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  userRegister(){
    console.log(this.register)
  }

  checkPassword(group: FormGroup): any {
    const pass = group.controls['password'].value;
    const confirmPass = group.controls['confirmPassword'].value;
    return console.log(pass,confirmPass);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="w-full min-h-screen grid place-items-center">
    <div class=" min-w-[40vw] min-h-[40vh] bg-gray-100 rounded-md   drop-shadow-2xl text-neutral-900 font-semibold
    " >
    <form [formGroup]="register" action="" class="flex flex-col justify-evenly items-center w-full min-h-[35vh]" (ngSubmit)="userRegister()">
            <h1 class=" text-4xl mb-5">Sign-up</h1>
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center  w-full">
                
                <input class="p-3 w-1/2 text-center bg-neutral-200 text-gray-700 rounded-md text-lg drop-shadow" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" formControlName="usuario">
                <span  *ngIf="this.register.get('usuario')?.invalid && this.register.get('usuario')?.touched">El usuario requerido</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center   w-full">  
                <input class="p-3 w-1/2 text-center bg-neutral-200 text-gray-700 rounded-md text-lg drop-shadow"   type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" formControlName="password">
                <span  *ngIf="this.register.get('password')?.invalid && this.register.get('password')?.touched">la contra es  requerido</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center   w-full">  
                <input class="p-3 w-1/2 text-center bg-neutral-200 text-gray-700 rounded-md text-lg drop-shadow"   type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" formControlName="repeatPassword">     
            </div>
            <div class="w-1/2 flex justify-evenly my-3">
                <button type="submit" class=" px-5 py-2 text-lg  rounded-sm bg-green-700 text-neutral-300 drop-shadow-xl  hover:scale-105  ease-in-out duration-300" [disabled]="this.register.invalid" [class.invalid]="this.register.invalid">Entrar</button>
                <button routerLink="/" class=" px-5 py-2 text-lg rounded-sm bg-red-800 text-neutral-300 drop-shadow-xl  hover:scale-105  ease-in-out duration-300">Volver</button>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                 <a routerLink="/register" class="border-b border-black">Crear cuenta</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help I truly don't know why it's happening

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605737/confirm-password-validation-in-angular-6) will help you.

Comment: are not `password` and `repeatPassword`? you has wroten "group.controls['confirmPassword']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `?` to mark as optional to avoid reading value of undefined.

```
checkPassword(group: FormGroup): any {
    const pass = group.controls['password']?.value;
    const confirmPass = group.controls['confirmPassword']?.value;
    // return console.log(pass,confirmPass);
    console.log(pass,confirmPass);
    return [pass, confirmPass];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, paranaaan! <3